# Why "cordova build ios" does not update Xcode project?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an existing Cordova project (with the iOS platform) containing a plugin I'm interested in.

I edited the list of the files in plugins/ios/src and updated the plugin.xml section for ios accordingly (I actually removed all files and replaced with mines).

I ran "cordova build ios", which generated errors as it tried to compile former files I removed.

Checking the Xcode workspace/project showed the file remained the the same as before.

I tried to run Cordova clean ios, successfully, but that changed nothing to the situation.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the command

```
cordova plugin add|remove <plugin_name>
```

For more information, you can read the docs https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/